# execsync fails if passed special characters

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to run a some commands on video files for processing. The video filenames may contain special characters like spaces, ' and ", among others. Because of this, my first attempt breaks on multiple files:

objMedInfo = JSON.parse(proc.execSync('mediainfo "' + currentfilename + '" --output=JSON').toString());

I then thought perhaps a different format would be more robust:

objMedInfo = JSON.parse(proc.execSync("mediainfo", [currentfilename,"--output=JSON"]).toString());

However, it won't run at all. Can someone help?

**(Particularly, why doesn't the second form work?)**

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this will help, and seems like a band-aid.

[execSync in node.js doesn't run shell command properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34768326/execsync-in-node-js-doesnt-run-shell-command-properly)

Hopefully can provide some help until someone smarter sees this :).

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape the quotes and prevent any cmd injection shinanigans.

```
function shellescape(a) {
  let ret = []
  a.forEach(function (s) {
    if (/[^A-Za-z0-9_/:=-]/.test(s)) {
      s = "'" + s.replace(/'/g, "'\\''") + "'"
      s = s.replace(/^(?:'')+/g, '').replace(/\\'''/g, "\\'")
    }
    ret.push(s)
  })
  return ret.join(' ')
}

currentfilename = 'filenames"with\'quotesAnd Spaces;shutdown now;.jpg'

console.log('mediainfo ' + shellescape([currentfilename]) + ' --output=JSON')

// mediainfo 'filenames"with'\''quotesAnd Spaces;shutdown now;.jpg' --output=JSON
```